# Require the "Other" off-topic close reason to be specified

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, close-reasons, close-dialog

It appears that it's possible to select the "Other" off-topic close reason, and vote to close without actually providing a close reason. This results in a custom close reason and comment which read:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about

[image: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about]

It should be required that someone actually alter the comment text before being able to submit the "Other" close reason.

Comment: But what about questions that *are actually* about

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Your question would be **off-topic** if it _was actually_ about

Comment: <sigh> Some people pointed out that the initial requirement was a little too long, and forced unneeded verbosity (which is usually *my* specialty). We adjusted to accommodate that point, but it sounds like now it's a *little* too short.  We're looking into it.

Comment: @Jaydles Perhaps just remove the default text, or require that it be changed to something other than what's there, even if the minimum is still just 30, that way someone intentionally giving a bad reason can do so easily, but you won't just forget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validation for this case added in build 2013.7.19.1249 (meta), 2013.7.19.874 (sites)

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is [really fixed](http://serverfault.com/questions/525247/zimbra-zcs-on-ubuntu-12-04-x86#comment598629_525247), surely it should check that the comment isn't a subset of the boilerplate text too (punctuation ignored) ?

Comment: It just checks against the boiler plate text, ignoring trailing whitespace

Comment: Yes I know but like my link shows it doesn't really help to get people to leave reasonable comments.

Comment: The check you're suggesting wouldn't enforce it either. You have to at least press some keys on the keyboard now before you can submit.