# Can we include the default text when creating a custom off-topic close vote in iOS?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, ios-app, close-reasons

I was on a [question on ELL earlier](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65883/topic-sentence-and-thesis-statement-usage) and needed to vote something closed. I was on my iPad at the time and submitted a close vote with a custom "other" reason. I'm so used to the default text: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because"... being included on the site that I missed it when I was writing my close reason.

Is it possible to auto-fill the default text in the custom off-topic close vote field?

This would additionally require that a solution similar to what was done [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185942/require-the-other-off-topic-close-reason-to-be-specified) is implemented to prevent users from simply hitting "Submit" without actually adding a reason while (hopefully) still allowing users to delete the default text if they do not want to use it.

Because pictures are pretty:

#### Current:

[image: Current View]

#### Proposed:

[image: Proposed View]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been added in 1.3.2.226 and will be in the next App Store build.  The submit button is disabled when the comment is blank or equal to the initial text.

Also, I went ahead and tidied up some things in the flagging flow (enabled landscape orientation, fixed text sizing, fixed HTML rendering, made comment header scrollable for small devices).

Comment: Wow-you've been really speedy in pushing out new versions! Thanks for this, and the many other, improvements!